# how to locate the file which is saved in documents folder of the iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am creating a file pdf in iphone application and it is saved in the documents it work fine on simultor i can also see the files.but how can i see this file when run the app on iphone device is there any way to get the file using itunes or any utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Organizer.So example...

[image: Organizer]

Comment: Although I don't suggest，you can try to use iTools actually .

Answer (score 1):

You can use itools.
1. Install itools
2. Connect your device with computer and open itools.
3. Go to "Apps" Tab, select your app.
4. Click on "document" icon,your app's document directory is opened.
5. Select the file and click "Export."

I know this is a late answer, but just in case it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer a document from your ios app to computer, enable File Sharing in your app. Set the boolean flag “UIFileSharingEnabled” in your info.plist. Now when you connect the device and scroll to the bottom in the Apps page in itunes, there you can see all the files that are in your Documents folder in your app.